# need help in creating custom search for cpt

Tags: php, wordpress

Search should show only related taxonomy posts, but it's taking whole cpt posts

I am creating one job board from scratch, I have created one custom post type named as jobs, created taxonomy as job location, defined functions in functions.php, created one search page as follows:

step1:Created CPT named as jobs

```
//added cpt
function codex_custom_init() {

register_post_type(
        'Jobs', array(
          'labels' => array('name' => __( 'Jobs' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'Jobs' ) ),
          'public' => true,
          'show_ui' => true,
          'capability_type' => 'post', 
          'hierarchical' => false, 
          'rewrite' => true,
          'has_archive' => 'jobs',
          'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
              'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-megaphone',
          /*'taxonomies' => array( 'category' )*/
        )
      );
       }
    add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Step2: created taxonomy

```
//taxonomy as joblocation
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_taxonomies', 0 );
    function create_my_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'joblocation',
        'jobs',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Job Location',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Job Location',
                'new_item_name' => "New Job Location"
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Step3: my form on page.php

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">  
   <span class="screen-reader-text"></span>
   <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Job Openings" id="search">
   <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
   <input type="hidden" name="taxonomy" id="taxonomy" value="joblocation">
</form>
```

Step4: Created search.php

```
<!--query starts-->
            <?php if ( have_posts() && strlen( trim(get_search_query()) ) != 0 ) : ?>
             <h1>Search Results for &nbsp;<small><span class="search-for"><?php echo get_search_query(); ?></span></small></h1>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?></a>

                    <?php else : ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ?>">
                            <div class="open-positions">
                                <h2><?php the_title()?></h2>
                                <div><strong>Key Skills:</strong> <?php the_field('key_skills')?></div>
                                <div><strong>Location:</strong> <?php the_field('location')?></div>
                                <div><strong>Years of Experience:</strong> <?php the_field('years_of_experience')?></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>


                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <br/><br/>
                 <a href="javascript:history.back()" id="goback">&#8656; &nbsp;Go Back</a>
            <?php else : ?>

                <h1>No results were found that match your search criteria</h1>
                <br/><br/>
                <div class="no-results-search"><a href="javascript:history.back()" id="goback">&#8656; &nbsp;Go Back</a></div>
            <?php endif ;?>
        <!--query ends-->
```

Step5: Created location filter as

```
<?php
   $args = array(
               'taxonomy' => 'joblocation',
               'orderby' => 'name',
               'order'   => 'ASC'
           );

   $cats = get_categories($args);

   foreach($cats as $cat) {
?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>">
           <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
      </a>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Problem:

If a user is on New Jersey (taxonomy locations), after search user is able to see New York job posts also in search results.

Answer (score 1):

if you want filter by user you should save job_location in user meta then tax_query as follow :

`$tax_query = array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'joblocation',
        'terms'            => '1',
        'field'            => 'term_id',
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'joblocation',
        'terms'            => '2',
        'field'            => 'term_id',
      ),
    );`

Answer (score 0):

Read more about it here: When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts().

You have to use WP_Query to fetch posts what you need. Read documentation for it. In your case the query could be like this:

```
      $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'Jobs',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'joblocation',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'NewJersy',
            )
        ),
));


        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
           $the_query->the_post();
            // Show Posts ...
        endwhile;
/* Restore original Post Data 
 * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the 
 * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset.
*/
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: As I am having only one page to display all the job locations as taxonomy-joblocation.php, so how the ('terms' => 'NewJersy')will work for all the locations??